# Find the shortest path or the fastest path

Tags: java

I'm given a file with 600000 roads that are connected with junctions. I have to make a program that finds the shortest path between 2 junctions. But it also has to be possible to find the fastest path between 2 other junctions. I was thinking of using the BFS-algorithm to solve this problem, but I don't know if that's the right way to go. I also found some other [links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) that use Dijkstra's algorithm to solve this problem.

I'm not looking for a complete code mashup, but I just want to know if I'm heading in the right direction.

PS: The input files look like this:

```
4370 6701 3079 2019 60
32840 9113 17817 7483 30
40758 13107 3445 2505 30
3074 11089 19209 2960 40
```

...

In the following format:
Roadnumber - Start junction - End junction - Distance (in meters) - Speed limit (in km/h)

EDIT (for future reference): I decided to use Dijkstra's algorithm to solve this problem and it worked like a charm. Thank you very much everyone! Turns out it only takes a few seconds to find the shortest path between 2 nodes in a graph of over 600000 nodes.

Comment: I think you're heading in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, Dijkstra's algorithm is the way to go. For shortest path use the distance between two junctions, and for fastest use the time it takes to travel between two junctions.

Comment: Thank you. So would it be a good idea to save the junctions in a hashmap that links the junction to a connected road?

Comment: You're correct to say you need to use Dijkstra's algorithm. You might want to look into [graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)) and the different ways you can represent them (eg. adjacency list, adjacency matrix) in order to implement the Dijkstra.

Comment: @PieterVerschaffelt That is definetly one way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dijkstra is the good way to go here. You just need to select a proper weight for the edges to represent distance and time...but that is really simple.